# Drivers for graphics and cpu of amd with UBUNTU 16.04LTS

Tags: 16.04, drivers, 64-bit, amd-graphics, amd-processor

I am looking to install drivers to my UBUNTU 16.04, AMD A8-7650K Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G × 4 , AMD KAVERI (DRM 2.43.0 / 4.4.0-116-generic, LLVM 5.0.0); but I couldn't find the appropriate driver for this linux distribution, can someone redirect to where I can download this driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that currently there are no supported drivers for this OS, UBUNTU 16.04LTS from AMD.

I guess this is why no one could answer my question.